# Google Api Calendar for Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a calendar application for Android devices currently done with phone calendar portion and it's working fine; I am able to show calendar, add events and delete events. But in my application there is an option to change calendar from phone to Google Calendar. How do I open a Google calendar and how do I add events in that calendar?

I have downloaded google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta but don't know how to use it; I also downloaded calendar-android-sample, but it's giving an error.

Comment: @Mike i am facing same issue, If you want to see more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209710/google-calendar-api-access-not-configured-in-android

Answer (score 1):

There's a Calendar Android sample app at the google-api-java-client project page:

http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to check google's reference site. i have been looking for a good source to come up with connecting my app to google calendar api but i found nothing better than this:

[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)