# google calendar api access not configured in android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have implemented google calendar API in android from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-android-sample/?repo=samples#calendar-android-sample/src%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

sample works fine but authentication issue is there

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
 {
   "domain": "usageLimits",
   "message": "Access Not Configured",
   "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
 }
],
"message": "Access Not Configured"
}
```

I have also enabled calendar API

[image]

Am I missing any configuration??

help!! Thanks.

Comment: i found clue from http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : 
Just need to add client ID (package name + SHA1 finger print)... 
For SHA1 finger print download [this](http://www.lazgosoftware.com/kse/index.html).

[image]
[image]