# Task android sample error

Tags: android

I am download task-android-sample(http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=479). But when i run this example on my android device, I m get error

The error appears here in this function

```
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
Log.d(Tag, "doInBackground");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Task> tasks =
    client.tasks().list("@default").setFields("items/title").execute().getItems();
Log.d(Tag, "трассировка");
if (tasks != null) {
  for (Task task : tasks) {
    result.add(task.getTitle());
  }
} else {
  result.add("No tasks.");
}
activity.tasksList = result;

}
```

description client

```
final com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks client;
client = activity.service;
```

in what could be the problem? I am a novice, please help.

```
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778): {
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):   "code": 403,
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):   "errors": [
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):     {
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):       "domain": "usageLimits",
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):     }
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):   ],
04-23 08:55:06.789: E/TasksSample(3778):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
```

Comment: the answer of this question should help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209710/google-calendar-api-access-not-configured-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static final String KEY = null;
```

make sure that you added key in place of null in `ClientCredentials.java`

Comment: I dont have ClientCredentials.java, where i can find this?

Comment: 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server refuses to allow the requested action. So make sure that you pass correct credentials and did not exceed usageLimits

Answer (score 0):

AsyncLoadTasks

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.tasks.android;

import com.google.api.services.tasks.model.Task;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class AsyncLoadTasks extends CommonAsyncTask {
  final String Tag="States";
  AsyncLoadTasks(TasksSample tasksSample) {
    super(tasksSample);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
    Log.d(Tag, "doInBackground");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Task> tasks =
    client.tasks().list("@default").setFields("items/title").execute().getItems();
    Log.d(Tag, "трассировка");
    if (tasks != null) {
  for (Task task : tasks) {
    result.add(task.getTitle());
  }
} else {
  result.add("No tasks.");
}
activity.tasksList = result;

  }

  static void run(TasksSample tasksSample) {
    new AsyncLoadTasks(tasksSample).execute();
  }
}
```

CommonAsyncTask

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.tasks.android;

import     com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityI    OException;
import     com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.IOException;


abstract class CommonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
  final String Tag="States";
  final TasksSample activity;
  final com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks client;
  private final View progressBar;

  CommonAsyncTask(TasksSample activity) {
    Log.d(Tag, "CommonAsyncTask");
    this.activity = activity;
    client = activity.service;
    progressBar = activity.findViewById(R.id.title_refresh_progress);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d(Tag, "onPreExecute");
    super.onPreExecute();
    activity.numAsyncTasks++;
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  @Override
  protected final Boolean doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
    Log.d(Tag, "Boolean doInBackground");
    try {
      doInBackground();
      return true;
        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException)     {
      Log.d(Tag, "1");
      activity.showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
      availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode());
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
  Log.d(Tag, "2");
  activity.startActivityForResult(
      userRecoverableException.getIntent(), TasksSample.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
    } catch (IOException e) {
  Log.d(Tag, "3");
  Utils.logAndShow(activity, TasksSample.TAG, e);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected final void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
Log.d(Tag, "onPostExecute");
super.onPostExecute(success);
if (0 == --activity.numAsyncTasks) {
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (success) {
  activity.refreshView();
    }
  }

  abstract protected void doInBackground() throws IOException;
}
```

TasksSample

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.tasks.android;


import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.tasks.TasksScopes;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



public final class TasksSample extends Activity {


  private static final Level LOGGING_LEVEL = Level.OFF;

  private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

  static final String TAG = "TasksSample";

  static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;

  static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;

  static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2;

  final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

  final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

  GoogleAccountCredential credential;

  List<String> tasksList;

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks service;

  int numAsyncTasks;

  private ListView listView;
  final String Tag="States";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.d(Tag, "onCreate");
// enable logging
Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client").setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL);
// view and menu
setContentView(R.layout.calendarlist);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Google Accounts
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, TasksScopes.TASKS);
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
// Tasks client
service =
    new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-TasksAndroidSample/1.0").build();
  }

  void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(final int connectionStatusCode) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Log.d(Tag, "run");
    Dialog dialog =
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode, TasksSample.this,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
  }
    });
  }

  void refreshView() {
Log.d(Tag, "refreshView");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasksList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
Log.d(Tag, "onResume");
super.onResume();
if (checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
  haveGooglePlayServices();
}
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d(Tag, "onActivityResult");
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
  case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      haveGooglePlayServices();
    } else {
      checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
    }
    break;
  case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
    } else {
      chooseAccount();
    }
    break;
  case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
      String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
      if (accountName != null) {
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
        editor.commit();
        AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
      }
    }
    break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
Log.d(Tag, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
Log.d(Tag, "onOptionsItemSelected");
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menu_refresh:
    AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
    break;
  case R.id.menu_accounts:
    chooseAccount();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }


  private boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
Log.d(Tag, "checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable");
final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
  showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
  return false;
}
return true;
  }

  private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
Log.d(Tag, "haveGooglePlayServices");
// check if there is already an account selected
if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
  Log.d(Tag, "user to choose account");
  // ask user to choose account
  chooseAccount();
} else {
  Log.d(Tag, "load calendars");
  // load calendars
  AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
}
  }

  private void chooseAccount() {
Log.d(Tag, "chooseAccount");
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
  }

}
```

Utils

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.tasks.android;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Utils {

  public static void logAndShow(Activity activity, String tag, Throwable t) {
 //   Log.d(Tag, "onPostExecute");
Log.e(tag, "Error", t);
String message = t.getMessage();
if (t instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException) {
  GoogleJsonError details = ((GoogleJsonResponseException) t).getDetails();
  if (details != null) {
    message = details.getMessage();
  }
} else if (t.getCause() instanceof GoogleAuthException) {
  message = ((GoogleAuthException) t.getCause()).getMessage();
}
showError(activity, message);
  }
```

/**

```
  public static void logAndShowError(Activity activity, String tag, String message) {
String errorMessage = getErrorMessage(activity, message);
Log.e(tag, errorMessage);
showErrorInternal(activity, errorMessage);
  }


  public static void showError(Activity activity, String message) {
String errorMessage = getErrorMessage(activity, message);
showErrorInternal(activity, errorMessage);
  }

  private static void showErrorInternal(final Activity activity, final String errorMessage) {
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
    });
  }

  private static String getErrorMessage(Activity activity, String message) {
Resources resources = activity.getResources();
if (message == null) {
  return resources.getString(R.string.error);
}
return resources.getString(R.string.error_format, message);
  }
}
```

It is my code. What I can fix?